# Linear discriminant analysis: link between transformation and classification.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, machine-learning

I have understood that LDA can be used both for transforming the data (e.g. dimensional reduction) and for classification. But I would like to understand the link between these two operations.

Let W and B the intra-class and inter-class covariance matrices, respectively. I read that linear transformations are computed by eigendecomposition of $W^{-1}B$ in order to maximise $$\arg\max_{a \in \mathbb{R}^p} \frac{a^T B a}{a^T W a}$$ Then I read that the decision rule for an observation $x$ can be $$\arg\min_k (x-\bar{X}_k)W^T(x-\bar{X}_k)$$ But what is the link between these two optimizations ? Is the transformed space in LDA linked to the classification ? I suppose it is, and for exemple the [sklearn class](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.discriminant_analysis.LinearDiscriminantAnalysis.html) enables both transformation and prediction after training. But I don't manage to understand it clearly.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case (projecting data), the transformed data is expressed by
$z = \mathbf{w}_\mathrm{LDA}^T \mathbf{x}$.

In the second case (binary classification), the decision rule comes from the ratio
$$
h(\mathbf{x})
=
\log
\frac{P(y=1|\mathbf{x})}{P(y=2|\mathbf{x})}
=
\log
\frac{P(y=1)}{P(y=2)}
+
\log
\frac{P(\mathbf{x}|y=1)}{P(\mathbf{x}|y=2)}
$$
where
$P(\mathbf{x}|y=c)
= \mathcal{N}
\left(\mathbf{x};\mathbf{m}_c,\mathbf{\Sigma} \right)
$
If we assume equiprobable class, the decision rule
writes
$$
h(\mathbf{x})
=
+\frac12
\left( \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{m}_2 \right)^T
\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}
\left( \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{m}_2 \right)
-\frac12
\left( \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{m}_1 \right)^T
\mathbf{\Sigma}^{-1}
\left( \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{m}_1 \right)
$$
and this justifies your statement about the decision rule for an observation $\mathbf{x}$.
Note that your statement will be wrong in the general case.

This expression can be further simplified as
$$
h(\mathbf{x})
=
b + \mathbf{w}_\mathrm{LDA}^T \mathbf{x}
$$
Thus LDA classification adds the information of a threshold  in the transformed space to decide which class to attribute to an observation.